# Passing an object as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, object, parameters

I'm currently running into a few problems surrounding passing an objects return value through a function. My function is prototyped in .h and defined in .cpp. the function for example `Class::function(int value);` takes in an integer of value. When I'm calling the object `objectName name;` and passing it through as `Class::function(name);`.

```cpp
// foo.h
class foo
{
     void function(int value);
}


//foo.cpp
void foo::function(int value)
{
     // CODE HERE
}


//main.cpp
int main()
{
     objectName name;
     foo::function(name);
}
```

The errors that I am receiving go along the lines of:

> Main.cpp:43:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘class::function(objectName&)’
>       name.function(name); // passes value to the function

Comment: class is a keyword.  Also, you can’t declare that thing in a function. Can you show something actually compilable?

Comment: Ok, it’s a [mre] now.  Good.

Answer (score 2):

The call `foo::function(name);` is triple wrong.

1. It's a call to a static function, but `function` is not static, so you need a instance of `foo` to call the function:

```
foo myFoo;
myFoo.function(0);
```

2. `function` is private, so it can not be used, outside of `foo`. All class members are by default private, so you need to declare it as public:

```
class foo {
  public:
    void function(int);
}
```

3. `function` takes an int as parameter, but you pass some object of type `objectName`. That's more a design issue, what parameter should `function` take? `int` or `objectName`?
   Maybe you want

```
//header
class foo {
  public:
    void function(objectName &);
}

// cpp
void foo::function(objectName &value) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration and definition of `foo` is correct. However, that is not how you create and use objects in C++.

```
int main() {
  foo foo_obj; // Create an object of type 'foo' named 'foo_obj'
  foo_obj.function(1); // call function named 'function' on the object 'foo_obj' 
                       // and pass integer (=1) as an argument

  return 0;
}
```

You should definitely pick up a good [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/7699037)

Answer (score 0):

I see an allocated variable named `name`, and it has a type `objectName`.

I see no allocation of any other objects, especially of type `foo`.

You can't call a class method, like `foo::function()` without an object of type `foo`.  (except static declarations, which you are not using and do not need)

Mainly, that error you see is because you only have a class method that takes an `int` parameter, and no function that takes a parameter of type `objectName`.